# Android app: send post to a user's friend without knowing its id in advance

Tags: android, facebook, sendmessage

I want my app to offer the possibility to send some text to the facebook wall of a friend.
Here is what I have so far,

```
    private void postOnFriendsWall() {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("to", ""); 
            facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params, new DialogListener()
```

it makes it possible to send a message to my own wall. 
I was trying to display all the friends by letting the id parameter empty, but it doesn't work, it only offers me to post on my own wall. Is there a facebook dialog where the user can choose who he wants to send the message to?

I have seen other answers where it is easy to do but only WHEN YOU KNOW IN ADVANCE the friend's ID.
I don't know the friend's id of the users of my app, so how to get the list dynamically?

Edit: just thought it would make my question more clear if I described the flow I want:

1. User logs in to Facebook on my app (done)
2. By tapping a button, user chooses who he wants to send the message to (i don't know how to have this)
3. User sends the message

Comment: I doubt if that's possible. I have tried this a while back but failed.

Comment: Hey Enigma, thanks for your input, I have done a lot of research and indeed there is nothing out there to do that. Still, I don't understand why this is not possible. Do you know if this is a Facebook policy thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by using graph api.
What you have to do is

1) Get the Friend List (with name and facebook ID)

2) Make a "POST" request by using graph api and "FriendID/feed" as the graph URL

---

The following is my code. You should try to know more about graph api and JSONObject before use my code.

1) Get Friend List

```
public JSONArray GetFriendList(){
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    String resp="";
    JSONArray resp_json=null;
    try {
        resp = fb.request("me/friends", params, "GET");
                    resp_json=new JSONArray(resp);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    //...
    } catch (IOException e) {
    //...
    }catch(JSONException e){
            //...
}
    return resp_json;//JSONArray of friend list, try to use debug mode to browse the content and parse it yourself,get a JSONObject from the JSONArray and get the user ID of that JSONObject
};
```

2) Post Friends Wall

```
public String PostWall(String Message,int Level,String FriendID){
 //FriendID can be grepped form the function above
|/*REMARK:Privacy Level
* level 0 ==>only me
* level 1==>friend only
* level 2==>public
*/
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", Message);
JSONObject privacy = new JSONObject();
try {
    switch (Level){
        case 0: 
            privacy.put("value", "SELF");
            break;
        case 1: 
            privacy.put("value", "ALL_FRIENDS");
            break;
        case 2: 
            privacy.put("value", "EVERYONE");
        break;
    }
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    //
}
params.putString("privacy", privacy.toString());
String resp= "";
try {
    resp = fb.request(FriendID+"/feed", params, "POST");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
try{
    resp = new JSONObject(resp).getString("id");
    return resp;//The post ID
}catch(JSONException e1){
    //
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you have any tutorial how to achieve this? Some code and more details would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to learn how to use graph api by studying the simple example in the facebook-android-sdk. Feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks man, I don't have time right now to test it but it's definitely something I can start from

Comment: You should be aware that this ability is going away soon, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/ .. "We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog."